# Domain Already Exists in the Apache configuration

Tags: apache, dns, cpanel, whm

I'm getting an error:

Account Creation Status: failed

(XID s9wshe) The domain "mydomain.com” already exists in the Apache configuration.

This site was originally on Server 1. These are the nameservers:

NS1.DOMAIN.COM
NS2.DOMAIN.COM

He bought a secondary server. These are the nameservers:

NS3.DOMAIN.COM
NS4.DOMAIN.COM

I'm trying to move sites from the 1st server to the new server. He has add-on domains and sub accounts inside individual accounts in the WHM.

This specific website was added on inside one of these accounts (instead of being given it's own account in WHM). I believe that is why I am having this issue.

My question is what is the best way to configure the new account on the secondary server without taking the old site down for anything other than the domain nameserver change?

Comment: If domain is already added as addon or parked domain, you cannot add it as separate domain without removing from addon/parked domain.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out which server is currently being used by the nameservers of the domain. It sounds like you may have the DNS tied between the servers. As long as the domain is pointed at the other server's nameservers you can simply delete the DNS zone on the server you are trying to create the account on and then you should be able to add it. Afterwards, simply create the DNS zone again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a GoDaddy shared hosting with multiple add-on domains, When I tried to delete an addon domain and recreate it again, I got this error (Domain already exists in the Apache configuration). I fixed it by going to the **alias**  **under the domain section in Cpanel**. Then deleted the alias. Waited a bit, then try to do the steps again. It worked for me.